# Named objects vs. temporary objects: Is it better to avoid named objects when possible?

Tags: c++

The following is an excerpt I found from a coding style documentation for a library:

> Where possible, it can be better to use a temporary rather than
>   storing a named object, eg:
>
> DoSomething( XName("blah") );
>
> rather than
>
> XName n("blah"); DoSomething( n );
>
> as this makes it easier for the compiler to optimise the call, may
>   reduce the stack size of the function, etc. Don't forget to consider
>   the lifetime of the temporary, however.

Assuming the object does not need to be modified and lifetime issues are not a problem, is this guideline true? I was thinking that in this day and age it wouldn't make a difference. However, in some cases you couldn't avoid a named object:

```
XName n("blah");
// Do other stuff to mutate n
DoSomething( n );
```

Also, with move semantics, we can write code like this since the temporaries are eliminated:

```
std::string s1 = ...;
std::string s2 = ...;
std::string s3 = ...;
DoSomething( s1 + s2 + s3 );
```

rather than (I've heard that the compiler can optimize better with the following in C++03):

```
std::string s1 = ...;
std::string s2 = ...;
std::string s3 = ...;
s1 += s2; 
s1 += s3;  // Instead of s1 + s2 + s3
DoSomething(s1);
```

(Of course, the above may boil down to `measure and see for yourself`, but I was wondering if the general guideline mentioned above has any truth to it)

Comment: I'd have to say I use variables when the temporaries get really long or have the same parts used in multiple temporaries. Readability and DRY first imo.

Comment: you can use `std::move` if you are using C++11

Comment: @chris: Definitely, readability over optimization.

Comment: Note that if your mutating methods are "fluent" (that is, they `return *this`), you can use still avoid a named object in your example.

Comment: Also, the reason `s1 += s2; s1 += s3` may be faster than `s1 = s1 + s2 + s3` isn't about temporary vs. named variables, but about mutating `+=` vs. copying `+`.

Comment: One last thing: In these cases, you can do better than just "measure and see for yourself"—you can also compile with `-S` and see for yourself. Of course you can't always even be sure which _assembly_ is faster on your platform without measuring—there are some cases where an "optimization" that the compiler does ends up slowing things down in practice. But you can at least tell whether you're preventing your compiler from optimizing a given case (which is usually more important than whether you're theoretically preventing an optimization that may or may not happen anyway).

Comment: I'm with Chis, go for readability and let your compiler take care of the rest. Remember the 80-20 (or 90-10) rule and put your effort there.

Comment: @abarnert: Thank you for the insight. I gather from your comments and the answers, that this "guideline" seems to be a premature optimization.

Comment: @JesseGood: Yes. Plus, many well-known premature optimizations for C++ are often pessimizations with modern compilers. (For example, the "always pass non-trivial objects by const reference" usually makes for slower code if the function's going to make a copy internally, but plenty of coding guidelines still recommend it.)

Comment: AFAIK, there is no difference between the release builds of the 2 'XName' examples in VS2010. Modern optimization is a very powerful process.

Comment: And yet using temporaries makes the code much more streamlined. Even if anything else was similar, that still makes for a very good reason, no? I'd be quite disgusted seeing your string examples, given that code is first and foremost to be written by humans and at the very least a work of art. Code that *looks* verbose and slow need not be slow, but that doesn't make it beautiful code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main job of the compiler frontend is to remove names from everything to resolve the underlying semantic structures.

Tending to avoid names does help avoid taking addresses of objects unnecessarily, which can unintuitively stop the compiler from manipulating data. But there are enough ways to get the address of a temporary that it's all but moot. And named objects are special in that they are not eligible for constructor elision in C++, but as you mention, move semantics eliminate most expensive unnecessary copy-construction.

Just focus on writing readable code.

Your first example does eliminate a copy of `n`, but in C++11 you can use move semantics instead: `DoSomething( std::move( n ) )`.

In the example `s1 + s2 + s3`, it's also true that C++11 makes things more efficient, but move semantics and elimination of temporaries are different things. A move constructor just makes construction of a temporary less expensive.

I was also under the misimpression that C++11 would eliminate the temporaries, as long as you used the idiom

```
// What you should use in C++03
foo operator + ( foo lhs, foo const & rhs ) { return lhs += rhs; }
```

This is actually untrue; `lhs` is a named object, not a temporary, and it is not eligible for the return value optimization form of copy elision. In fact, in C++11 this will produce a copy, not a move! You would need to fix this with `std::move( lhs += rhs );`.

```
// What you should use in C++11
foo operator + ( foo lhs, foo const & rhs ) { return std::move( lhs += rhs ); }
```

Your example uses `std::string`, not `foo`, and that `operator+` is defined (essentially, and since C++03) as

```
// What the C++03 Standard Library uses
string operator + ( string const & lhs, string const & rhs )
    { return string( lhs ) += rhs; } // Returns rvalue expression, as if moved.
```

This strategy has similar properties to the above, because a temporary is disqualified for copy elision once it is bound to a reference. There are two potential fixes, which give a choice between speed and safety. Neither fix is compatible with the first idiom, which with `move` already implements the safe style (and as such is what you should use!).

#### Safe style.

Here there are no named objects, but the temporary bound to the `lhs` argument cannot be directly constructed into the result binding to a reference stops copy elision.

```
// What the C++11 Standard Library uses (in addition to the C++03 library style)
foo operator + ( foo && lhs, foo const & rhs )
    { return std::move( lhs += rhs ); }
```

#### Unsafe style.

A second overload accepting an rvalue reference and return the same reference eliminates the intermediate temporary completely (no reliance on elision), allowing a chain of `+` calls to be converted perfectly into `+=` calls. But unfortunately it also disqualifies the remaining temporary at the start of the call chain from lifetime extension, by binding it to a reference. So the returned reference is valid until the semicolon, but then it's going away and nothing can stop it. So this is mainly useful inside something like a template expression library, with documented restrictions on what results can be bound to a local reference.

```
// No temporary, but don't bind this result to a local!
foo && operator + ( foo && lhs, foo const & rhs )
    { return std::move( lhs += rhs ); }
```

---

Evaluating library documentation as such requires a little bit of evaluation of the library authors' skill. If they say to do things a certain quirky way because it's always more efficient, be skeptical because C++ isn't purposely designed to be quirky, but it is designed to be efficient.

However in the case of expression templates where temporaries include complicated type computations which would be interrupted by assignment to a named variable of concrete type, you should absolutely listen to what the authors say. In such a case, they would be presumably much more knowledgeable.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to clarify one point. For a non-member function `operator+`, if it takes its lhs by value, there would be an extra copy when passing in an object, so I don't think it would transform directly to `( s1 += s2 ) += s3`, unless I am missing something the only way for them to be the same is if you know the lhs is a temporary object.

Comment: @JesseGood Yes, `s1` may be copied to produce an object to hold the intermediate and final results, but you need that anyway. The result of `s1 + s2` may be a temporary, identical to the initial lhs argument, which is a copy of s1, and is also identical to the lhs argument of `(s1+s2)+s2` and the final result. If used to initialize a named variable (for example if `DoSomething` accepts its parameter by value), copy elision eliminates it and you have no temporaries whatsoever. If the compiler can't do any of these elisions, then C++11 requires it to move-construct instead if possible.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Are you sure that if you have `T foo(T obj) { return obj; }` then `T t; foo(t)` can be optimized out? That's only possible if the copy-constructor has no observable side-effects. By contrast, even if it *does* have observable side-effects, `foo(T())` can elide the copy. So I think this answer is wrong...

Comment: I don't think that something like `XName n("blah"); DoSomething( std::move(n) );` is desirable. Maybe if you do stuff in between  creation and `DoSomething()` call. Creating a named object, just to move from it right afterwards, leaving `n` in an unpredictable state, is potentially dangerous. `n` is still in scope and potentially used after having been moved. This is an unnecessary pitfall that should _ihmo_ be avoided.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Some people consider `T t = some_very_long_expression_that_barely_fits_on_a_line; foo(t, some_other_very_long_expression_that_barely_fits_on_a_line);` to be more readable, so if they don't know about this pitfall, they would make named temporaries (and would freak out if you didn't). (I don't.)

Comment: @Mehrdad Oops, my answer is wrong, although not about that particular example — the answer does already say `foo(t)` produces a copy. In the `s1+s2+s3` example though, the function parameter objects are all named entities, not temporaries, and their copy- or move-construction is visible even from a return value temporary. I'll fix it later, just got up.

Comment: @Mehrdad That is a matter of style/personal preference and I think a security hazard outweighs it. Since the question is about temporary vs. named object, `std::move` should not be a suggestion here. (As I said you may want to move from an object after creating and altering it. But you can't use a temporary here anyway. That case may be reasonable, but moving from an object that has been constructed the statement before isn't. Imho this should neither be considered nor suggested.)

Comment: @Mehrdad OK, finally fixed. More analysis than this question probably warrants, but it's good review for me :)

Comment: @Pixelchemist I agree they are different things, but the question does mention `move` and it's important to highlight the difference… which I did, a little, in this update.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I never even mentioned moving, you're the one who's been talking about `move`. :P Anyway, glad you fixed it.

Comment: @Mehrdad are you the one who you asked the question?

Comment: Oh oops, I confused @Pixelchemist's response regarding `move` with yours, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I think the accepted answer is wrong. Avoiding naming temporary objects *is* better.

The reason is that if you have

```
struct T { ... };
T foo(T obj) { return obj; }

// ...

T t;
foo(t);
```

then `t` will be copy-constructed, and **this cannot be optimized out** if the copy-constructor has observable side-effects.

By contrast, if you had said `foo(T())`, then calling the copy-constructor could be avoided completely, *irrespective* of potential side-effects.

Therefore, avoiding naming temporary objects is better practice in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I may decide to unaccept the accepted answer, but Im not sure yet.

Comment: "Avoiding naming temporary objects is better" is nonsense. There is no such thing as a named temporary object. "If the copy constructor has observable side effects" is also wrong because side effects don't enter into it. It gets copied (or an identical copy is constructed per the as-if rule) because `t` must still exist with its original value after the call. And you're extrapolating way too broadly.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I used the word "temporary" in its colloquial meaning, no need to be pedantic. It makes perfect sense if you take off your C++ Official Specification glasses.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few points:

- You can never know exactly what compiler will optimize and what it will not. Optimization is a complex thing. Optimizer writers tend to be very careful not to break something. It is possible to hit a bug that optimizer mistakenly decides that something should not be optimized. Coding standards in compilers are extremely high. Nevertheless they are written by humans.
- This particular coding style excerpt does not seem me very reasonable. Our days compilers are almost always good. It is hard to imagine that optimizer will confuse something in `XName n("blah"); DoSomething(n);` - this code is too simple.

I would put similar coding guideline this way:

- Write your code in a way that is easy to understand and modify;
- Once performance problems are observed, look into generated code and think
  how to please the compiler.

It is better to address the problem in this order, not the opposite way.